# Why does accessing an array element throw an array-as-string error in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, string, comparison

I've done some searching and I didn't find any posts that quite answered my question.
I have a PHP array generated, for the sake of argument, with this code:

```
$i = 5;
for($i = 0; $i < $j; $i++) {
   $multiArray[0][$i] = $i;
   $multiArray[1][$i] = $i;
}
```

When I try to access it with:

```
for($i = 0; $i < $j; $i++) {
   echo "$multiArray[0][$i]";
   echo "$multiArray[1][$i]";
}
```

I get:

> Notice: Array to string conversion on line 3
>
> Notice: Array to string conversion on line 4
>
> ...x4

When I replace `echo` with `printf("%d", $multiArray[0][$i])` then it prints fine. Why do I have to explicitly tell PHP that I'm asking for an int when the element I'm accessing is clearly an int (and PHP knows it, via `var_dump()`)? I'm not accessing the array, but an element *within* the array.

Thanks

Comment: try to remove double quotes.for($i = 0; $i < $j; $i++) {
   echo $multiArray[0][$i];
   echo $multiArray[1][$i];
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Simple double quoted variable interpolation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) supports up to *one* nested element. In other words, `"foo[0][1]"` is interpreted as `"{$foo[0]}[1]"`. That means it tries to interpret the array `$foo[0]` as a string at that point to interpolate it into the string.

But using quotes here at all is entirely nonsensical. You don't want string interpolation, you just want to output a variable value:

```
echo $multiArray[0][$i];
```

Answer (score 0):

just try this:

```
for($i = 0; $i < $j; $i++) {
 echo $multiArray[0][$i]; 
 echo $multiArray[1][$i]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is parsing the string not the array, try to remove the quotes.The [] brackets after the array are considered as a string not the as a paremeter.Use the code below

```
<?php
$j = 5;
for($i = 0; $i < $j; $i++) {
   $multiArray[0][$i] = $i;
   $multiArray[1][$i] = $i;
}

for($i = 0; $i < $j; $i++) {

   echo $multiArray[1][$i];
}
```

Hope this helps you